# Half donut chart with values

Tags: r, donut-chart

[This is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHXhq.png)

I have this code in R, but it makes a "donut" however I want to create half a donut. With the information at the top with 85% in dark blue and 15% in light blue with a red line at 37%. But whatever I do I cannot get ride of the blue part on the left side of the black line.

Moreover, it would be totally perfect if there where text labels also mentioning the 85%,15% and 37 %

People are Saying I need to switch back to Excel but I want to proof it is possible in R too ;)

```
# Verwijder alle vorige objecten
rm(list = ls())

library(ggplot2)

# Dummy data voor de chart
data <- data.frame(
  categorie = c("Categorie 1", "Categorie 2"),
  waarde = c(0.85, 0.15)
)

# Kleuren per deel
kleuren <- c("#468bcc", '#cae6f2')  # donker en lichtblauw

# Pijl locatie
arrow = 0.37

# Berekeningen voor de halve cirkel
total <- sum(data$waarde)
data$percentage <- data$waarde / total
data$start <- cumsum(data$percentage) - data$percentage
data$einde <- cumsum(data$percentage)

# Maak de plot
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = 1, y = waarde, fill = categorie)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = start, ymax = einde * 2), color = NA) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = arrow, xend = 2, yend = arrow), color = "red", size = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +  # Draai de figuur niet
  xlim(0.5, 2.5) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# Voeg zwarte lijnen toe bij 0 en 100 graden
plot <- plot +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 0, xend = 2, yend = 0), color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 1, xend = 2, yend = 1), color = "black", size = 1)

# Pas de kleuren van de delen aan
plot <- plot + scale_fill_manual(values = kleuren)

# Plot de halve cirkel donut chart
print(plot)
```

Comment: To continue to use ggplot2 with geom_segment, ` coord_polar(theta = "y", start = -pi/2)` gets you the right starting position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want. This is done with the **rAmCharts4** package.

```r
library(rAmCharts4)

gradingData <- data.frame(
  label = c("Bottom", "Top"),
  color = c("lightblue", "darkblue"),
  lowScore = c(0, 15),
  highScore = c(15, 100)
)

amGaugeChart(
  score = 37, minScore = 0, maxScore = 100, gradingData = gradingData,
  hand = amHand(innerRadius = 40, width = 15, color = "red", strokeColor = "black")
)
```

[image]

You can replace "bottom" and "top" by the percentages.

Comment: A small Question, How can I remove the text label 'Top' below the figure?

Comment: @user21699241 Add `scoreLabelFont = amFont(fontSize = 0)`.

Comment: Ah okay now it workks perfectly!